# How to make an auto clicker in Android with react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to create an Android app with react native that I can implement the auto clicker with, and I can click on the mobile screen or in other apps automatically and as many times as I want.
But I did not find any document about this

[Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OhTqe.jpg)

Comment: React Native primarily focuses on building UI components for mobile apps and doesn't directly support functionalities like simulating user interactions outside of its own app context. Additionally, automating clicks on other apps without user consent can be considered malicious behavior and violates most app stores' policies. For legitimate purposes like accessibility features, you should explore Android's native development capabilities and adhere to platform guidelines and user privacy standards.